# C++ compiler thinks my constructor definition is a method

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm getting the following errors:

```
C:\Users\James\cavewhere\dewalls\src\unit.cpp:6: error: C2511: 'dewalls::Unit::Unit(QString,dewalls::UnitType *)' : overloaded member function not found in 'dewalls::Unit'
C:\Users\James\cavewhere\dewalls\src\unit.cpp:9: error: C2550: 'dewalls::Unit::{ctor}' : constructor initializer lists are only allowed on constructor definitions
```

unit.h:

```
#ifndef UNIT_H
#define UNIT_H

class UnitType;

#include <QString>

namespace dewalls {

class Unit
{
public:
    Unit(QString name, UnitType *type);

private:
    QString _name;
    UnitType *_type;
};

}

#endif // UNIT_H
```

unit.cpp:

```
#include "unit.h"
#include "unittype.h"

namespace dewalls {

Unit::Unit(QString name, UnitType *type) :
    _name(name),
    _type(type)
{

}

}
```

What for the love of god am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's closed, problem was that I forgot to move the `class UnitType` declaration inside the namespace.  I'm about to answer my own question

Comment: If I could shorten the code into the simplest example, would people consider this a valid question?  The compiler errors were not informative, and any smart person who's new to C++ could easily get thrown off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `UnitType` should be in your namespace too

```
namespace dewalls {
    class UnitType;
}
```

Comment: I know this question was asked a while back, but could you kindly offer an explanation why this is? Forward declaring outside the namespace has a different effect as inside?

Comment: Yes the class `UnitType` does not exist in the global namespace, it only exists within the `dewalls` namespace, so the forward declaration has to reflect that